# Overriding detail page on clicking save button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have multiple VF pages **apex/vf_table1, apex/vf_table2** and "**apex/vf_table3**" in iframes in a single VF page "**apex/vf_table**". All uses the same  save button. How can I override the save method of the vf in iframes to prevent them from going into their respective detail page?

This is in my controller..

```
 public PageReference save()
 {
   upsert fb;
   PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/apex/vf_table?accId= account.Id');
   return newocp;
  }
```

This is my VF..

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible for you to alter the code of the pages in the frames? If they are using the standard `save` action, you can change them to use the [`quicksave`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std_actions.htm) standard action instead.  Unlike the standard `save` action it does does not redirect after the save.

Here is an example that uses quicksave on an Account standard controller.  This is taken from the example on the [standard actions documentation page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std_actions.htm) and modified to use quicksave.  When the user clicks the Quick Save button the record is saved.  Note that there is no method that you have to implement in a controller extension.  The standard controller action takes care of the quick save for you.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!quicksave}" value="Quick Save"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.site}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.type}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.accountNumber}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks peter. Yes, I wanted exactly like the quicksave feature. But I am unable to find any article on how to use quicksave in a vf. Please help if you have any references.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use custom controllers. The overhead would be that you will have to implement your own methods/action like edit delete etc.